# Linq to XML, merge elements with same attribute but different namespace

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I would like to know if its is possible to merge these elements with different namespaces;

```
     <imsss:objectives>
        <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID="ettiquette_completed"/>
          <imsss:objective objectiveID="previous_sco_completed">
              <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="com.scorm.golfsamples.sequencing.forcedsequential.playing_completed" readNormalizedMeasure="true" readSatisfiedStatus="true" />
          </imsss:objective>
      </imsss:objectives>
      <adlseq:objectives>
        <adlseq:objective objectiveID="ettiquette_completed">
          <adlseq:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="com.scorm.golfsamples.sequencing.forcedsequential.ettiquette_completed" readCompletionStatus="true" writeCompletionStatus="true"/>
        </adlseq:objective>
        <adlseq:objective objectiveID="previous_sco_completed">
          <adlseq:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="com.scorm.golfsamples.sequencing.forcedsequential.playing_completed"  readCompletionStatus="true" writeCompletionStatus="false"/>
        </adlseq:objective>
      </adlseq:objectives>
```

so basically I would like to end up with

```
<imsss:objectives>
        <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID="ettiquette_completed">
          <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="com.scorm.golfsamples.sequencing.forcedsequential.ettiquette_completed" readCompletionStatus="true" writeCompletionStatus="true"/>
        </imsss:primaryObjective>
          <imsss:objective objectiveID="previous_sco_completed">
              <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="com.scorm.golfsamples.sequencing.forcedsequential.playing_completed" readNormalizedMeasure="true" readSatisfiedStatus="true" readCompletionStatus="true" writeCompletionStatus="false/>
          </imsss:objective>
      </imsss:objectives>
```

At the moment I have a linq query that puts all elements together with the same objectiveid attribute;

```
                XElement seqColl = getSequencingCollection(identifier);
                var ImssObj = seqColl.Element(imsss + "objectives").Elements();
                var AdlObj = seqColl.Element(adlSeq + "objectives").Elements();
                var newEl = from o in ImssObj 
                            join a in AdlObj on o.Attribute("objectiveID").Value equals a.Attribute("objectiveID").Value
                            select new XElement(o.Name, new XAttribute(o.Attribute("objectiveID")), o.Elements(), a.Elements());
```

(the getSequencingCollection method works correctly to get all sequencing information from the xml, as it needs to get local sequencing and shared sequencing)

Thanks all.

Comment: well i've done quite a specific solution to this, if anyone wants to see it then let me know.  I cant imagine it would help anyone though.  BUT if you know of a different way rather than a long c# function ive used then please feel free to let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i've done quite a specific solution to this, if anyone wants to see it then let me know. I cant imagine it would help anyone though. BUT if you know of a different way rather than a long c# function ive used then please feel free to let me know. Thanks